# XML schema : 'ref' or 'name' must be present in a local element declaration

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm making an XML schema but the following error happens for all my elements :

> One of 'ref' or 'name' must be present in a local element declaration.

I don't understand because I have a `name` or `ref` present in my XSD document as you can see here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SCCOAMCD="urn:SCCOA-schemaInfo">
<xsd:import namespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm" schemaLocation="balisesXrm.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.moss.fr/2011/connecteur_xrm"/>

<xsd:complexType xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" name="typeAssociation">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element xmlns:ns0="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm" ns0:ref="balisesXrmType"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="plugin">
  <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element xmlns:ns0="http://www.moss.fr/2011/connecteur_xrm" ns0:name="xrm:header" type="header"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

You can find here my balisesXrm.xsd document :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
       targetNamespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm"
       xmlns:b="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm">


<xsd:complexType name="balisesXrm">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="attribut" />
            <xsd:element name="variable" />
            <xsd:element name="param" />
            <xsd:element name="java" />
            <xsd:element name="historisation-date" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There error is telling you exactly the problem:

> One of 'ref' or 'name' must be present in a local element declaration.

So for

```
  <xsd:element xmlns:ns0="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm" 
               ns0:ref="balisesXrmType"/>
```

remove the `ns0` from `@ns0:ref`

```
  <xsd:element ref="balisesXrmType"/>
```

and now you will have a `@ref` attribute as the error indicates you were missing.  You've not provided a full MCVE, but this looks likely to be off.  Typically a referenced element wouldn't have a `Type` suffix, so perhaps you instead mean,

```
  <xsd:element ref="balisesXrm"/>
```

note that to reference `balisesXrm` in another namespace, declare a namespace prefix for that namespace, `xmlns:ns0="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm"`, locally or better, at the root level as you'll likely need it elsewhere, and then use it on the `@ref` attribute *value*, not the *name*:

```
  <xsd:element ref="ns0:balisesXrm"/>
```

or

```
  <xsd:element name="balisesXrm" type="ns0:balisesXrmType"/>
```

There are too many other problems with your XSD to address in a single question, but this answer will at least allow you to progress past your current problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I use a namespace locally because while i am importing my balisesXrm.xsd (as i edited), a new error comes : 
the prefix 'b' is not declared (i delete the namespace creation in my element and rename all my balisesXrm as b:balisesXrm).
What i haven't specified is i use a XSLT document to produce this schema.

Comment: Sorry, I'd originally declared a new namespace prefix, `b`, for you before realizing that you already had used `ns0` for that purpose.  I've updated the answer to use your original `ns0`.  Note, of course, that the namespace prefix only derives its significance by virtue of its associate with a full namespace URI, but we do have to get the `b` or the `ns0` bound correctly.  It is now.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes i understood the prefix's name has not importance, but my prefix is not declared according to my error whereas I create it in my balisesXrm.xsd document  and i import it in my main document.

Comment: The scope of an XML namespace prefix definition extends only to the elements contained by the declaring element; it does not extend to importing XSDs.

Comment: Oh ok ! Thanks a lot for your patience and help. Even when i declare `xmlns:nr0="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm"` in my schema, the error : 
`Cannot resolve the name 'nr0:balisesXrm' to an 'element declaration' component` comes...

Comment: Your balisesXrm.xsd has no `xs:element` declaration for `balisesXrm`; it only has a type declaration.   Re-read what I wrote about element vs types.  In your recently added imported XSD, consider naming your type with a `Type` suffix and then using `  <xsd:element name="balisesXrm" type="ns0:balisesXrmType"/>` to reference it.

Comment: Ok i get it. Thanks a lot for your help.